# Manually Clearing Native Cache Only Clearing Primary Site, Not Current MSM Instance

Tags: multi-site-manager, cache

### Overview

#### Current System

- EE 2.9.2
- MSM 2.1.7 Build: 20140715
- Redis server v. 2.8
- Current cache driver is set to Redis

We have enabled EE to use native redis caching and have found that when we manually clear native cache, following the steps below, that the key values in redis related to the primary site are cleared, but remain intact for the current msm instance.

#### 1. Steps To Reproduce Bug

- Visit the control panel
- Switch to a msm site from the top right of the screen
- Go to Tools > Data > Clear Caching
- Select all caches from the list
- Click Submit
- Review Redis key values

#### 2. Expected Behavior

- Redis key values related to the currently selected msm are cleared
- Redis key values for other msm sites remain intact

#### 3. Buggy Behavior

- Keys related to the primary msm site are cleared
- Keys related to the current msm instance still exist

Has anyone else experienced this behavior?